# Product sigma algebra of countable cocountable sets

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to prove the following proposition:

> Let $\Omega $ be an uncountable set and let $$\mathcal F = \{A \subset \Omega: A \textrm{ countable or } A^c \textrm{ countable} \}.$$
>   If $B \in \mathcal F \otimes \mathcal F$, then for $B$ or $B^c$ there exists $A\subset \Omega $ countable such that $B \subset (\Omega \times A) \cup (A \times \Omega)$ or $B^c \subset (\Omega \times A) \cup (A \times \Omega)$.

I already identified all $\mathcal F$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable functions $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ with the functions constant up to a countable set. So I tried to use this fact and construct such a map with projections and indicator functions. My idea was that $B\in \mathcal F \otimes \mathcal F \iff 1_{B}$ is $ \mathcal F \otimes \mathcal F$-measurable but I didn't quite get what I wanted. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the standard procedure of showing that the conclusion is true when $B$ is measurable rectangle and the class of all sets for which the conclusion holds is a sigma algebra?

Comment: No, I'll try that!