# Both $f(x,\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot,y)$ $\mathcal{A}$ measurable,but $f(x,y)$ not $\sigma \left ( \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{A}\right )$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

From Richard Bass' *Real Analysis for Graduate Students* Version 3.1  p.94:

> $\textbf{Example 11.5}$  There exists a set $X$ together with a partial order $"\leq"$ such that $X$ is uncountable but for any $y \in X$, the set $\{x\in X: x\leq y\}$ is countable.  The $\sigma$-algebra is the collection of subsets $A$ of $X$ such that either $A$ or $A^c$ is countable.  Define $\mu$ on $X$ by $\mu(A) = 0$ if $A$ is countable and 1 if $A$ is uncountable.  Define $f$ on $X\times X$ by $f(x,y)=1$ if $x\leq y$ and zero otherwise.  Then $\int \int f(x,y)\, dy\, dx = 1$ but $\int \int f(x,y)\, dx \, dy = 0$.The reason there is no contradiction is that f is not measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra.

I don't understand why $f$ is not measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the  $\sigma$-algebra the collection of subsets $A$ of $X$ such that either $A$ or $A^c$ is countable.
Actually,How can I prove either   $\left\{\left (x,y \right )\in X\times X\right | x\le y  \}\notin \sigma \left (  \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{A}\right )$ or $\left\{\left (x,y \right )\in X\times X\right | x> y  \}\notin \sigma \left (  \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{A}\right )?$

Comment: This [condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201620/product-sigma-algebra-of-countable-cocountable-sets) for sets in the product-σ-algebra should work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra, then since $f$ is non-negative, by Tonelli’s theorem we have $$\int \int f(x,y)\, dy\, dx =  \int \int f(x,y)\, dx \, dy = 0,$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes,indeed.In an indirect way by applying Tonelli's theorem, we will get the contradiction.But in fact,I want to explain this  by directly proving  either   $\left\{\left (x,y \right )\in X\times X\right | x\le y  \}\notin \sigma \left (  \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{A}\right )$ or $\left\{\left (x,y \right )\in X\times X\right | x> y  \}\notin \sigma \left (  \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{A}\right ).$